# How to load a website from within a subfolder using HTACCESS?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website that will replace an existing website. The existing website is in the root (/public_html) folder. For now, I don't want to delete this site but instead want to store the new site in a subfolder (/public_html/live).

I need it so when someone accesses the site on the domain (eg http://www.example.com), the site within the subfolder will be loaded but the user won't know

Can I do this with a HTACCESS within the public_html folder?

---

Thanks guys. I've used the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /live/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /live/$1

# Add trailing slash to directories within live
# This does not expose the internal URL.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^live/(.*[^/])$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301]
```

This does indeed redirect to the subfolder. The problem is it redirects to the root domain (http://www.domain.com) for all pages (e.g http://www.domain.com/news, http://www.domain.com/events/test-event)

What's causing this redirect issue??

Cheers

Comment: tried mod_rewrite and set the rule to `RewriteRule . /live/`?

Comment: Thanks guys. Just updated the question with some details

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

you can install a plug-in like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/
to replace all the old urls to the new url, which is a better option than doing a mod_rewrite on .htaccess. there are ton of other plug-ins you can use; use the one that works best for you.

you want to physically rename the urls. mod_rewrite is rewriting to the new url. it will do the job, but its better this way. in a sense, on your new wordpress instance, you want to be able to track urls and keep traffic trends in order with the new urls.

make a copy of the old wordpress, place the new instance in a new directory, change the urls, then test your urls, then point the domain to the updated wordpress that has the new urls.

you should use mod_rewrite rules on .htaccess if you're going to need a specific url treatment, i wouldn't forward the entire site to the new domain. you should physically change the urls.